Datetimepicker no funciona correctamente, o aparece en español o se aplican todas las funciones que le puse
Estoy intentando usar un datetimepicker en español, que pueda usar las funciones como setDate y manejarlas con las funciones del datetimepicker.
Tengo un datetimepicker con las siguientes propiedades:
var datetimepickerprops = {
    language: "es",
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    todayHighlight: true,
    minuteStep: 1}

Y definí el locale de la siguiente manera, ya que si coloco en language: "ru", sí se ve en ruso, pero si pongo "es" no sale en español.
$.fn.datetimepicker.dates.es = {
        days: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
        daysShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Jue", "Vie", "Sáb"],
        daysMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sa"],
        months: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
        monthsShort: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
        today: "Hoy"
    };

Con esto sí se pone en español, pero no me funcionan las funciones del datetimepicker como la siguiente:
$("#id").datetimepicker('setDate',new Date());
Y me sale este error en la consola:
jquery.js:4123 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Object.formatDate (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:1744:1)
    at Datetimepicker.getFormattedDate (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:519:1)
    at Datetimepicker.setValue (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:503:1)
    at Datetimepicker.setUTCDate (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:476:1)
    at Datetimepicker.setDate (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:470:1)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:1481:1)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:385:1)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:207:1)
    at $.fn.datetimepicker (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:1473:1)

Cómo hago para que funcione todo bien y se muestre en español?

¿Que datatimepicker es? ¿versión? ¿has mirado en su documentación?

datetimepicker es un nombre común para un tipo de componente. Es como si dijeras "no me funciona el botón"

@Yussef Gracias por la iluminación :-)  Pero me refiero a que hay muchos "datetimepicker" en javascript por la red, y cada uno se configura como diga su documentación, por eso queria saber de cual estamos hablando, para ver si se ha dejado algo por configurar en alguna parte.

Esta pregunta es similar a: DatePicker en español. Si crees que es diferente, por favor pulsa en [edit],  para modificar la pregunta, dejando en claro en qué es diferente y/o cómo las respuestas a esa pregunta no son útiles para tu problema.

@masterguru Estimado que gusto en saludarlo !! El comentario no era para usted, era para el OP :P

@Yussef Jolin!  Ya me parecia a mi raro que justamente tu me hubieras dicho eso!  No me cuadraba, jeje,... en fin, me alegra ver que sigues por aquí :-) Y no me trates de Ud.!! Me hace parecer más viejo de lo que me siento :-D
